# On the random variable which denotes the number of flips, in a coin toss, it takes to get a run of $n$ successive heads

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

Let the probability of obtaining head, when a coin is tossed, be $p$. Let the coin be tossed, many times, independently and

$X_n :=$the number of flips it takes to get a run of $n$ successive heads.

How do I find  $E(X_{n+1}|X_n=k) $ ?

I'm completely clueless here, I don't know  what is the joint p.m.f. of $X_n$ and $X_{n+1}$. Or is there any clever way to do it ?

Please help

Comment: Aren’t they independent?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the event $\{X_n=k\}$. The next flip can be head with probablity $p$. In this case $X_{n+1}=k+1$. Or the next flip can be tail with probability $1-p$. Then we begin to flip a coin again after $k+1$ trials, and wait for the next possibility to get a run of $n+1$ successive heads. In this case we will wait in average $k+1+\mathop{\mathbb E}[X_{n+1}]$ tosses.

So
$$\tag{1}\label{1}
\mathop{\mathbb E}(X_{n+1}\mid X_n=k) = p\cdot (k+1) + (1-p)\cdot (k+1 + \mathop{\mathbb E}[X_{n+1}]).
$$
If you have a value $\mathop{\mathbb E}[X_{n+1}]$ you can use it here. If not, one can use Law of total expectation to obtain recurrence relation on $x_n=\mathop{\mathbb E}[X_{n}]$: 
$$
x_{n+1}=\mathop{\mathbb E}\mathop{\mathbb E}(X_{n+1}\mid X_n) =\mathop{\mathbb E}[ p\cdot (X_n+1) + (1-p)\cdot (X_n+1 + x_{n+1})]
$$
$$ 
= p\cdot (x_n+1) + (1-p)\cdot (x_n+1 + x_{n+1}).
$$
Rewrite it and get $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+1}{p}$. Since $x_1=\frac1p$, one can get 
$$
x_2=\frac1p+\frac{1}{p^2}, \ \ldots, \ x_{n+1} = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{p^i}=\frac{1-p^{n+1}}{p^{n+1}(1-p)}.
$$
Finally you can use it in (\ref{1})